# Any way to get notified of app updates?

Tags: update, store, windows-10-mobile, app-update

In Windows Phone 8.1 the Store was able to notify of pending app updates on the live tile as well as in the notification centre. Is there something similar in Windows 10 Mobile, for those who don't want automatic app updates? The Store live tile only seems to toggle through featured apps, and I've yet to see anything pop up in the notification centre. Or is opening the Store and checking for updates manually the only way?

Comment: This is a really annoying regression from the previous behavior, all the way back to WP7.0. **There's a number of items about this in the Windows Feedback app; I recommend up-voting them**.

Comment: Windows 10 Anniversary Update shows notifications for store app updates

Comment: @user2321864 Does it? I've yet to see this happen on my Lumia 950. Maybe you can add some details and/or a source and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

For now there's no way to get notified of app updates through the notification center or even the live tile in Windows 10 Mobile (Preview).

As CBHacking suggested, upvoting this feature on the Windows Feedback app would make sense.

Comment: What about third-party apps? Can any of them offer such functionality?

Comment: @Indrek: Third-party apps cannot, officially, tell what apps you have installed. (Unofficially, there are hacks that make it possible, so a homebrew app could totally do this. I don't think anybody has written one yet, but maybe somebody should.) Without knowing what apps you have installed, it wouldn't know which Store apps to check for updates.